# How mysqldump replaces special characters during dumping records?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, dump

i am trying to dump a particular row using java.

So that i retrieve the data by using record sets and i manually written sql script code by appending the dynamic records.

But my problem is i could not write the script for blob data fields.

Because there are some special characters are present inside blob type fields.

i need to know how mysqldump.exe is replacing special characters ?

If i know the detail means i can replace those characters as same as mysqldump process.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways: string and hexadecimal notation, e.g.:

- 'abc\' as string will be like this -> 'abc\\', all special characters are [escaped](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html)
- 'abc\' as hexadecimal will be like this -> 0x6162635C, you can test it using HEX function - SELECT HEX('abc\\');

You can choose one of those methods. Also, try to play with [--hex-blob](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_hex-blob) option and check results.